# list comprehension vs filter() vs set difference: which is the most efficient when filtering a set?

Tags: python, filter, set, list-comprehension, set-difference

Considering that I have:

- 1 array of integers converted as a set (named `neighbors`)
- 3 other sets of integers to avoid (named `forbidden1`, `forbidden2` and `forbidden3`)

__

```
neighbors = {6, 12, 9}
forbidden1 = {1, 4, 7, 8}
forbidden2 = {2, 5, 0, 3}
forbidden3 = {6, 9}
```

__

Which of the following solutions would be the most efficient at filtering out the forbidden values from the first set ? And why ?

**A/** list comprehension with `if` statement and logical operators `and`

```
[x for x in neighbors if x not in forbidden1 and x not in forbidden2 and x not in forbidden3]
```

**B/** list comprehension with `if` statement and union operators `|`

```
[x for x in neighbors if x not in forbidden1 | forbidden2 | forbidden3]
```

**C/** filter() with logical operators `and`

```
filter(lambda x: x not in forbidden1 and x not in forbidden2 and x not in forbidden3, neighbors)
```

**D/** filter() with union operators `|`

```
filter(lambda x: x not in forbidden1 | forbidden2 | forbidden3, neighbors)
```

**E/** set difference with union operators `|`

```
neighbors.difference(forbidden1 | forbidden2 | forbidden3)
```

Comment: My bet is on `E` since sets are basically optimized for membership checking. Also note that you can use a *set comprehension* in `A` and `B` by replacing `[ ]` with `{ }`.

Comment: right, I forgot about those. Thanks for the reminder. I would also bet on E but would need some explanations regarding what's happening under the hood.

Comment: That's entirely another question - determining which code runs faster is one thing, determining *why* it does so is a whole other beast.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it out (timeit python):

```
A) 294 ns ± 28.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
B) 297 ns ± 26.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
C) 300 ns ± 31.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
D) 294 ns ± 19.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
E) 291 ns ± 21.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

All are pretty much the same.